# Not able to open a QGIS project

Tags: qgis, error, menu

I have been able to open up projects in the past with no problem. However, today I started having issues. I've tried opening up my current project, but it's not working. I keep seeing the message "project loaded" but I stay on the same screen. I am able to open up past projects, but not the one I started today. I am also unable to start a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Qgis graphical interface (its window), doesn't exist without a project.
When you open a Qgis window without opening an existing project, you are just starting a new one.

When you open an existing project, the current project closes. If you close a project without opening an existing one, you are just starting a new project.

It seems to me that the one you started today is empty.

Comment: The project already existed. I had worked on it previously, but for some reason it wasn't opening that time. I'm not sure what happened, but it fixed itself so its all fine now.